# How to use the directory of the script for the entry point

Tags: python-3.x, entry-point

I am using setup.cfg for creating my entry point like so,

```
[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    package = package.app:main
```

And the entry point works, but I want it to be such that irrespective of where the entry point "package" is called from the working directory is changed to the directory of the script.

So is there a way for me to provide a path as the working directory for the entry point?

Comment: What are you doing? What is setup.cfg? Never seen something like this

Comment: Are you sure you are using python? Maybe a wrong question tag?

Comment: @TimWoocker I guess I didn't explain clearly, its a configuration file that can be used instead of setup.py https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/configfile.html